# SQL Query on finding difference of dates between current and previous row

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to find difference of 2 consecutive dates.
Firstly, I sort the dates in descending order, and then, I take the difference of every 2 consecutive row.

A sample is like this[image: Here]

Can someone please help me out?

Comment: What MySQL version you have?

Answer (score 2):

Something like this should do the trick:

```
set @PrevDate := (Date from table order by Date asc limit 1);

select Date, datediff(Date, @PrevDate) as DateDiff, 
    @PrevDate := Date as Increment
from table
order by Date asc;
```

You can use a variable to store the previous row's value, in this case `@PrevDate` is the variable which is set initially to the first Date value of the first row, with the same order as the main query.
The `@PrevDate` is needs to be reset with the current row's value, after the
`DateDiff` calculation.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use LAG function

```
select id,Group,Date,
datediff(day,lag(date,1) over (partition by Date order by Date asc), Date)
as Difference_2_days
from yourtable;
```

Comment: What is day inside datediff?

Comment: `day` inside `datediff()` is the unit of measure. It tells the function that you want the difference between two dates in number of days, as opposed to number of months or years.

Answer (score 0):

SELECT id, group, date, (DAY (date) -DAY(LAG(date) ) ) AS 'daysdiff'
FROM table

Answer (score 0):

Your data is rather awkward.  You seem to suggest that it has an ordering, but there are exact duplicates.  Let me assume that you have *another* column that correctly specifies the ordering, such as an "id" or "time" column.  If so:

```
select t.*,
       datediff(date, lag(date) over (partition by group order by date, <ordering col>)) as num_days
from t;
```

You can take your chances without the ordering column, but using window functions with `order by` when there are ties can lead to problems in some cases.